# Sencha Touch 2 KitchenSink Example Build Fails

Tags: build, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I'm Trying to build Kitchensink Example from Sencha Touch 2.2.1 GPL package. I'm Using Sencha CMD 3.1.2.342 but something is failing. here is the log:

```
C:\wamp2.1\www\sencha\examples\kitchensink>sencha app build testing
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] init-local:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[INF]
[INF] -after-init:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-build:
[INF]
[INF] sass:
[INF]
[INF] -before-sass:
[INF]
[INF] -sass:
[INF] [shellscript]
[INF] [shellscript] C:\wamp2.1\www\sencha\examples\kitchensink\resources\sass>co
mpass compile --boring --force
[INF] [shellscript] identical ../css/bb10.css
[INF] [shellscript] identical ../css/sencha-touch.css
[INF] [shellscript] identical ../css/wp.css
[INF]
[INF] -after-sass:
[INF]
[INF] page:
[INF]
[INF] -before-page:
[INF]
[INF] -page:
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\wamp2.1\www\sencha\examples\kitchensink\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:127: The f
ollowing error occurred while executing this line:
C:\wamp2.1\www\sencha\examples\kitchensink\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:121: javax
.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: Referenc
eError: "SenchaLogManager" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#6) in <Unknown sour
ce> at line number 6
```

Any idea what is wrong? what is "SenchaLogManager"?

Note: Custom Apps are building OK

Thanks

Comment: Even, any example dir app is failing to build...and repeat... own apps build fine.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at following thread at sencha forum

[Thread1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260413-sencha-upgrade-beta-not-working)

[Thread2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260404-quot-SenchaLogManager-quot-is-not-defined&langid=4)

someone at sencha forum posted as follows

> solved. Found Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.270 and install it. Worked with st2.2
>   and everything is ok now

you can see that it may be a mismatch between sencha touch frame work and sencha CMD

Comment: So, do you suggest to downgrade Sencha CMD to 3.1.1.270? should not be solved on later versions?